# CodeIgniter - Create dynamic html table using form helper functions?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've a dynamic table which adds more rows. Here is my table.

```
<table> 
  <thead>
    <tr class="success">
     <th>Bank/Lender</th>
     <th>Add More</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
   <tr>
    <td>
     <?php
       $data = array(
              'name' => 'debt_info_bank_name[]',
              'id' => '',
              'class' => 'form-control',
              'placeholder' => 'Bank/Lender Name'
              );
       echo form_input($data);
      ?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="add btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" value="Add More"  />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And Here is my javascript part:

```
    $(document).on('click','.add',function(){ 
    $(this).val('Delete');
    $(this).attr('class','del btn btn-danger btn-sm');
    var appendTxt = '<tr><td><?php  $data = array(
                                    'name' => 'debt_info_bank_name[]',
                                    'id' => '',
                                    'class' => 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder' => 'Bank / Lender Name'
                                  );
                                  echo json_encode(form_input($data)); ?></td><td><input class="add btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" value="Add More"  /></td></tr>';
    $("#dyn_table > tbody > tr:last").after(appendTxt);
    });

    $(document).on('click','.del',function(){ 
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

    });
```

It adds rows but with quotes"" in each td element. How can i correct it?

**Note**: If i add fields in javascript code using html elements like

```
 var appendTxt = '<tr><td><input type="text" placeholder="Bank/Lender Name"  /></td> <td><input class="add btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" value="Add More" /></td></tr>';
```

then it goes fine but i want to add fields in `codeigniter style` because it is more safe to do that.

Comment: Why do you use `json_encode`? Just `echo form_input($data);` should do the trick?

Comment: removing json_encode leads to javascript error: " SyntaxError: unterminated string literal ". Actually it adds extra line break before closing of </td> thats why it gives error. @Mudshark

Comment: I would look at the script in the browser, after the `form_input` has been inserted. `json_encode` is definitely the wrong solution to the syntax error problem.

Comment: can you please come up with solution for me. @Jerry

Comment: I really can't, not without looking at the code as it's rendered in the browser. Remove the `json_encode` and then view the actual html using your browser's inspector. to get rid of extra whitespace around the generated input, use php's `trim()` method. But I think you will find that's not the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

remove json_encode from here. just echo

```
 echo form_input($data); ?></td><td><input class="add btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" value="Add More"  /></td></tr>';
```

Comment: this project is closed and dusted it too. but thanks.